# Python, thread-function doesn't execute and the object disappears

Tags: python, multithreading, function, vizard

We are trying to run this code in Python, but while the function print_time works, the TestReactionTime doesn't execute (it doesn't even print).
The calls to both functions are identical.

Also, and independently, when we release the ball for the first time and try to grab it again, it disappears.

Any help with any of the problems will be grateful.

(The program we are using is Vizard)

```
import viz
import math
import viztask
import vizinfo
import thread
import time

count = 0
boolTime = False

viz.setMultiSample(4)
viz.fov(20)
viz.go()

viz.phys.enable()
viz.phys.setGravity( [0, 0, 0] )
viz.window.setFullscreen()

viz.setOption('viz.model.apply_collada_scale',1)
ball = viz.add('ball.dae')
ball.setPosition([-0.1,1.5,4])
#ball.setScale([0.75,0.75,0.75])
ball.collideSphere()


viz.setOption('viz.model.apply_collada_scale',1)
path = viz.addChild('path.dae')
path.setPosition([-1,1.0,4])
path.collideMesh()

#collision
path.enable(viz.COLLIDE_NOTIFY)
def onCollide(e):
        global count 
        count = count+1
        print(count)

viz.callback( viz.COLLIDE_BEGIN_EVENT, onCollide )

#mouse
viz.mouse.setOverride(viz.ON) 
link = None 

**def TestReactionTime(threadName):**
    print 'boolTime: '
    print(boolTime)
    while boolTime:
        #Wait for next frame to be drawn to screen
        d = yield viztask.waitDraw()

        #Save display time
        displayTime = d.time

        #Wait for keyboard reaction
        d = yield viztask.waitMouseUp(viz.MOUSEBUTTON_LEFT)

        #Calculate reaction time
        reactionTime = d.time - displayTime
        print(reactionTime)

def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

def grabBall():
    global link
    global boolTime
    boolTime = True
    print("grab ")
    print(boolTime)
    try:
        #thread.start_new_thread( TestReactionTime,() )
        thread.start_new_thread( TestReactionTime, ("Thread-3", ) )
        thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
        print("execute thread")
    except:
        print "Error: unable to start thread"
    link = viz.grab( viz.Mouse, ball )


def releaseBall():
    global link,boolTime
    boolTime = False
    link.remove()
    link = None

vizact.onmousedown(viz.MOUSEBUTTON_LEFT,grabBall)
vizact.onmouseup(viz.MOUSEBUTTON_LEFT,releaseBall)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you create threads, you should `join` them so that the main program waits until each thread is completed executing.

The `thread` module does not provide any provision for thread to wait. You should be using the recomended `Threading` module

change the `thread.start_new_thread` calls with the `Thread()`

```
    from threading import Thread

    #do something

    try:
       thread1 = Thread( target = TestReactionTime, args = ("Thread-3", ) )
       thread2 = Thread( target = print_time, args = ("Thread-1", 2, ) )

       thread1.start()
       thread2.start()

       thread1.join()
       thread2.join()

   #do the rest
```

Comment: Thanks, @nu11p01n73R, we changed that. But still it doesn't enter the TestReactionTime function. It doesn't even print the "booltime".